# Dataset from a Dataset in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I laid out the report, and I do a query that returns 30+ rows for a given period of time.  One for each workflow.  Now, I want to take that dataset (so the query only runs once) and define 6 datasets from it that filter it based on a single selected row.  I will populate 8 boxes on the form for each of those datasets.

It appears that when you create a new dataset, it wants to go back to the datasource and ask you about all the data from that one again.

I was able to create a dataset that is a filtered view of the query and figured I could live with creating 6 datasets that ran the query each time  filtering it differently each time.  So, I need to do a 'copy' on the dataset and 'paste' it back in as a new dataset that is the same as the other one except with a new name.

I also need to set the default values for the Start/End date to be the 1st of last quarter, and the first day of this quarter.  Is there a way to create calculated default values or do I need to do a query to return that?

Comment: Can you please ask a more specific question, or explain what it is exactly you're trying to do? In particular these sentences are not clear:

>I want to take that dataset and define 6 datasets from it that filter it based on a single selected row. I will populate 8 boxes on the form for each of those datasets.

>it wants to go back to the datasource and ask you about all the data from that one again.

With that said, if the reports all use the same dataset, there should be no need to refresh the data. Design the subreports first, and then determine how to create the master (summary?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using table objects to create your report. you could use just 1 data set and add your filters to the table accordingly. just go to tablix properties>> filters tab.

for default values you can create expressions like for the first day of the current quarter:

```
=switch(DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today()) = 1, cstr(year(today))+"-01-01",
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today()) = 2, cstr(year(today))+"-04-01",
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today()) = 3, cstr(year(today))+"-07-01",
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today()) = 4, cstr(year(today))+"-10-01")
```

Comment: This looks good, I get a syntax error on today()   However, that got me going in the right direction for that. I had to add the CDate() and switch it to be last quarter. =CDate(switch(DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today) = 2, cstr(year(today))+"-01-01",
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today) = 3, cstr(year(today))+"-04-01",
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today) = 4, cstr(year(today))+"-07-01",
DatePart(DateInterval.Quarter,today) = 1, cstr(year(today)-1)+"-10-01"))